# Failed decryption of RSA public key encrypted data on server side sent from client (Android)

Tags: java, android, encryption

Server sends public key encrypted data to client and so does the client to server.

Client-side decryption is fine. Server side is not.

Same decryption procedure seems to work on Android, however, it doesn't apparently on server side.

Here is my server-side decryption code:

```
int bytesRead;
int current = 0;
FileOutputStream fos = null;
byte[] EncryptedClientAES = new byte[10000];
InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
fos = new FileOutputStream("ClientAESFile");
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
bytesRead = is.read(EncryptedClientAES, 0, EncryptedClientAES.length);
current = bytesRead;
System.out.println("Size of read data: " + current);

bos.write(EncryptedClientAES, 0, current);

bos.flush();
bos.close();
fos.close();
clientSocket.close();

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
byte[] decryptedAESKeyOfClient = null;
decryptedAESKeyOfClient = cipher.doFinal(EncryptedClientAES);
```

This fails with *IllegalBlockSizeException* saying the data shouldn't be longer than 64 bytes which made me change the size of byte array *EncryptedClientAES* to *64* since the size of read data is *64* as well. Moving forward with that gave me *BadPaddingException*, however, the same procedure works on Android side.

Following is my encrypted data sending code from Android:

```
SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
KeyGenerator kg = null;
kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
kg.init(128, secureRandom);
SecretKey ClientSecretKey = kg.generateKey(); // Client AES is generated here.

String ServerModulus = ServerRSAPublicKey.substring(40, 194);
String ServerExponent = ServerRSAPublicKey.substring(214, 219);
BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger(ServerModulus, 10);
BigInteger bigInteger1 = new BigInteger(ServerExponent);

RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPublicKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(bigInteger, bigInteger1);
KeyFactory keyFactory = null;
try {
    keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
RSAPublicKey publicKeyOfServer = null;
try {
    assert keyFactory != null;
    publicKeyOfServer = (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(rsaPublicKeySpec);
} catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Cipher c = null;
try {
    c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
} catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    assert c != null;
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKeyOfServer);
} catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

byte[] encryptedBytes = null;
try {
    encryptedBytes = c.doFinal(ClientSecretKey.getEncoded());
} catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
OutputStream outputStream;
outputStream = client.getOutputStream();
assert encryptedBytes != null;
outputStream.write(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.length);

outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
client.close(); // closing the connection
```

**My decryption code which is working on Android side is**:

```
Socket client = new Socket("192.168.1.169", 4444);

int bytesRead;
int current = 0;
FileOutputStream fos;
byte[] EncryptedServerAES = new byte[100000];
InputStream is = client.getInputStream();
fos = new FileOutputStream("ServerAESKeyFile");
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
bytesRead = is.read(EncryptedServerAES, 0, EncryptedServerAES.length);
current = bytesRead;
do {
    bytesRead =
            is.read(EncryptedServerAES, current, (EncryptedServerAES.length - current));
    if (bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
} while (bytesRead > -1);

bos.write(EncryptedServerAES, 0, current);
bos.flush();
fos.close();
bos.close();
client.close(); // closing the connection

// try to decrypt and get AES key back.
BigInteger Modulus;
BigInteger publicExponent;
BigInteger privateExponent;
BigInteger primeP;
BigInteger primeQ;
BigInteger primeExpP;
BigInteger primeExpQ;
BigInteger crtCoeff;
Modulus = new BigInteger(ClientPrivateKey.substring(32, 161));
publicExponent = new BigInteger("10001");
privateExponent = new BigInteger(ClientPrivateKey.substring(198, 327));
primeP = new BigInteger(ClientPrivateKey.substring(334, 399));
primeQ = new BigInteger(ClientPrivateKey.substring(406, 471));
primeExpP = new BigInteger(ClientPrivateKey.substring(486, 551));
primeExpQ = new BigInteger(ClientPrivateKey.substring(566, 631));
crtCoeff = new BigInteger(ClientPrivateKey.substring(646, 711));

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
// realise client's private key string as private key.
RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec rsaPrivateCrtKeySpec = new RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec(Modulus, publicExponent, privateExponent, primeP, primeQ, primeExpP, primeExpQ, crtCoeff);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
RSAPrivateKey ClientPrivateKEY = null;
try {
    ClientPrivateKEY = (RSAPrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(rsaPrivateCrtKeySpec);
} catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, ClientPrivateKEY);
} catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    decryptedAESKeyOfServer = cipher.doFinal(EncryptedServerAES);
} catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**For the above successful decryption on Android (client) side, Server sent this data**:

```
Cipher c = null;
try {
    c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(SecureServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
 {
    try {
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKeyofClient);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SecureServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
byte[] encryptedBytes = null;
 {
    try {
        encryptedBytes = c.doFinal(ServerSecretKey.getEncoded());
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SecureServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

OutputStream outputStream;
outputStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.length);

outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
clientSocket.close(); // closing the connection
```

*This is how I am generating RSA keys on both sides*:

```
secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
try {
    keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(SecureServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

keyPairGenerator.initialize(512, secureRandom);
keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
```

I guess I am being dumb here.

---

**Update 1**:

It is still failing.

**This is my (Android) client-side encryption code**:

```
Cipher ciphertest = null;
ciphertest = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");
ciphertest.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
byte[] encryptedBytes = null;
encryptedBytes = ciphertest.doFinal(Bytes_to_encrypt);
```

**This is my server-side decryption code**:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding");
OAEPParameterSpec oaepParams = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", new MGF1ParameterSpec("SHA-1"), PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey, oaepParams);
byte[] decryptedAESKeyOfServer = null;
decryptedAESKeyOfServer = cipher.doFinal(EncryptedClientAES);
```

Error is either *IllegalBlockSizeException* (if *decryptedAESKeyOfServer* is of random huge bytes in size) or *BadPaddingException* (if *decryptedAESKeyOfServer* is 256 bytes in size; data which is received from client is of this much bytes).

---

**Update 2**

- I have fixed the data which was being sent from Android to server.
  *Client was sending null before this*.
- Android is reading null from server even though server is sending 256 bytes of data.

**Code on client side which is reading null from server**:

```
int bytesRead;
int current = 0;
FileOutputStream fos;
byte[] EncryptedServerAES = new byte[100000];
InputStream is = client.getInputStream();
fos = new FileOutputStream("ServerAESKeyFile");
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
bytesRead = is.read(EncryptedServerAES, 0, EncryptedServerAES.length);
data_size = bytesRead; // data_size is 0.
```

*Idk how, but, client is still (attempting) decrypting it and there is no crash!*.

**My stack trace**:

```
06-15 15:18:03.619 23489-23927/com.avineshwar.secureclient W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServerAESKeyFile: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
06-15 15:18:03.620 23489-23927/com.avineshwar.secureclient W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
06-15 15:18:03.622 23489-23927/com.avineshwar.secureclient W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
06-15 15:18:03.623 23489-23927/com.avineshwar.secureclient W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:127)
06-15 15:18:03.623 23489-23927/com.avineshwar.secureclient W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:116)
06-15 15:18:03.623 23489-23927/com.avineshwar.secureclient W/System.err:     at com.avineshwar.secureclient.Part3$SendMessage.doInBackground(Part3.java:128)
06-15 15:18:03.623 23489-23927/com.avineshwar.secureclient W/System.err:     at com.avineshwar.secureclient.Part3$SendMessage.doInBackground(Part3.java:115)
06-15 15:18:03.623 23489-23927/com.avineshwar.secureclient W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
06-15 15:18:03.623 23489-23927/com.avineshwar.secureclient W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-15 15:18:03.623 23489-23927/com.avineshwar.secureclient W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
06-15 15:18:03.623 23489-23927/com.avineshwar.secureclient W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-15 15:18:03.623 23489-23927/com.avineshwar.secureclient W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-15 15:18:03.623 23489-23927/com.avineshwar.secureclient W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**In *Part3.java*, Line 115 is just a blank line which I think is a reference to**:

```
private class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
```

**In *Part3.java*, Line 128 is**:

```
InputStream is = client.getInputStream();
```

Comment: are you using the same rsa public key on the server ?

Comment: C and S are using distinct key pairs. Public keys are transferred as a string and later I am realizing those strings into public keys on both the sides.

Comment: General advice: **Always use a fully qualified Cipher string.** `Cipher.getInstance("RSA");` may result in different ciphers depending on the default security provider. Nowadays, you should use OAEP instead of the default PKCS#1 v1.5 padding. So you should probably use `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");`

Comment: @ArtjomB. Sounds thoughtful. I'll update soon.

Comment: How are you sending the data? Is it at all possible you are getting a different string (have you tried comparing the sent and received data)?

Comment: @Tigger I uncovered some issues. Please see the upate 2.